# UIImageView with an image set through IB is taking about 10 seconds to appear once view is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have a `UIView`, and then I added another `UIView` as a child view to that view using the code below.

```
TestViewController* holesaw = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
holesaw.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height + 44, holesaw.view.frame.size.width, 454);
[self addChildViewController:holesaw];
[holesaw didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:holesaw.view];
```

child view has a `UIImageView` with an image that it is set to show through IB. It takes almost 10 seconds to load. Does anyone know why? I have tried the image as both .jpg and .png, and it is only a 200kb image to start with.

Comment: You are adding the view of another controller within the current controller? (and this view is containing the UIImageView)

Comment: Where are you running this code?  Might want to make sure it's on the main thread.

Comment: It's on the main thread.  and yes @sebastienFCT that's what i'm doing.

Comment: Are you downloading the image or you are loading from bundle?

Comment: It's in the app bundle.